# Moving mirrored UVs to other quadrant for baking

Tags: uv-image-editor

I'm exporting a model into substance painter 2 for baking/texturing, and I'm confused by what people tell me in regards to moving the mirrored UVs out of 0-1 space. I have a vague idea of how this works, but don't actually know how to do it in Blender with any precision. I only know how to move the UVs manually (G) until they visually line up with the texture, but that's hardly ideal.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the UV editor check the Coordinates **Normalized** property (*Properties Panel > Display*).

Instead of moving them manually in grab mode, you can enter values in grab, rotate or scale mode. They will appear in the menu bar of the active area (*image editor*). Minus <kbd>-</kbd> and <kbd>Backspace</kbd> work, while entering a value in a transformation mode.

To move some faces 100% out of the uv space, press the following: <kbd>G</kbd> > <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> > <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

With normalized coordinates many similiar transformations can be made, for example flipping or flopping vertices. Just set the cursor coordinates to (0.5, 0.5) and the Rotation/Scaling Pivot to 2D Cursor. Then scale with a value of -1 along x or y. (<kbd>S</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd> > <kbd>-</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> > <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

[image: Flipping UV Coordinates]